# Replace existing content = local storage + existing content. Javascript, WebStorage, LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

Um I trying to save the messages in "textBox" back in to localStorage and prepend it to "logContent" but when I refreshed the page the "logContent" is still empty with only original content exists.

```
<body>

<div class="modal-body"> 
    <input id="textBox" type="text" placeholder="Type Message" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {enterPressed();}">
    <p id="logContent">
            -- Logging is created --
    </p>
</div>

</body>
```

Here is my Javascript so I want to replace original content in "logContent" with textBox.value + original content in logContent and make display everything all the time even with you refresh the page. Thank you.

```
var today = new Date(); 
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
dd ='0'+ dd
} 

if (mm < 10) {
mm ='0'+ mm
} 

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

function enterPressed() {
localStorage.setItem("logs", document.getElementById("textBox").value);
if (textBox.value == "") {

}
else {
var logText = today + ":" + " " + localStorage.getItem("logs") + '<br>';
$("#logContent").prepend(logText); // Prepend textBox's content to the top of  "logContent".
textBox.value = ""; // To clear the textBox after enter is pressed.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original script did not provide the means to load the logs from `localStorage`, and stored new input under the "logs" key, while the intent was to prepend. The solution is quite simple: load from localStorage on page load, and overwrite `localStorage['logs']` with the contents of `logContents` as displayed on the page.

```
....

window.onload = function(){
    existing_log = localStorage.getItem("logs");
    console.log(existing_log);
    if (existing_log){document.getElementById("logContent").innerHTML = existing_log;}
}

function enterPressed() {
    if (textBox.value == "") {
        return;
    }
    else {
        var logText = today + ":" + " " + document.getElementById("textBox").value + '<br>\n';
        $("#logContent").prepend(logText); // Prepend textBox's content to the top of  "logContent".
        textBox.value = ""; // To clear the textBox after enter is pressed.
        localStorage.setItem("logs", document.getElementById("logContent").innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If you're going to do this kind of thing more often, you might want to look at a data-binding framework such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/). Angular integrates well with localStorage (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage), but similar frameworks offer similar solutions.